# how to start service and stop it at another activity in android

Tags: android, android-service, tracking

> my Service never stop until I uninstall the app #HELP!

**service class**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    GPSTracker myGps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
    Log.e("tracking...","");
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    GPSTracker myGps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
        Log.e("STOPPED!","");
    return super.stopService(myGps);
  }
}
```

** Start the Service At the Login Activity**

```
            Intent locationService = new Intent(Login.this, LocationService.class);
            startService(locationService);
```

**Stop the service At the employee Activity in option selected menu   **

```
     @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent serviceIntent;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.LogOut) {
        serviceIntent = new Intent(Employee.this, LocationService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        Log.e("OUT"," ");
         finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Try it using `getApplicationContext()` as first parameter to Intent constructor and call `stopSelf()` method in `stopService` method

Comment: What does your LocationService class look like?

Comment: @Bidhan I already paste the class above

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Actually it didn't work also ! this log ->         Log.e("STOPPED!","");
 which is in the stopService method in LocationService class not printed

Comment: what can I do now ? @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2 activities A and B u have, you should unbind service in B onStop(), then you can call stopService in A. Simply putting  stopService(serviceIntent); might give you and error about leaked service connection

```
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
    }
}

public void start() {
    // mContext is defined upper in code, I think it is not necessary to explain what is it 
    mContext.bindService(i, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.startService(i);
}

public void stop() {
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, ServiceRemote.class));
    mContext.unbindService(mServerConn);
}
```

and see in your code what you have done is u have stopped the service but i dont see you unbinding it, the correct procedure would be unbind it then stop it.

Comment: I don't understand! would you show me an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the command startService(service).

To start the service at the beginning of the app just bind it to all your activities. This way, when the activities are destroyed, the service stops.
Explained thoroughly [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Also, if you want the service to end when the app is closed(but not destroyed), just add unBindService method to an overrided onStop method.